# Geoserver executes sql twice & queries number of rows

Tags: geoserver

two issues with Geoserver - probably someone has experience of these...

**1. SQL statement executed twice**

I can see from Geoserver logs that the SQL is executed twice. This happens for all the layers and in several environments. Why ??

Here is the snapshot from my log file (actual sql hidden of course):

```
2022-06-27 08:57:40,366 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2022-06-27 08:57:40,448 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2022-06-27 08:57:40,452 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * ......
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 2.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8085/geoserver/
    outputFormat = application/json
    resolve = none
    resolveDepth = *
    resolveTimeout = 300
    resultType = results
2022-06-27 08:57:40,648 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2022-06-27 08:57:40,650 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2022-06-27 08:57:40,888 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2022-06-27 08:57:40,888 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "GEOLOC".ST_AsBinary() as "GEOLOC",...
2022-06-27 08:57:41,566 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2022-06-27 08:57:41,568 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2022-06-27 08:57:41,713 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2022-06-27 08:57:41,714 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "GEOLOC".ST_AsBinary() as "GEOLOC",...
2022-06-27 08:57:42,146 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2022-06-27 08:57:42,159 INFO [org.geoserver.flow] - releasing flow controllers for [WFS 2.0.0 GetFeature]
2022-06-27 08:57:42,159 INFO [org.geoserver.flow] - Request completed, running requests: 0, blocked requests: 0
```

**2. How to remove "select count(*)..."**

Geoserver executes always "Select count(*) ..." in order to find out how many rows is to be fetched. How to prevent this? I read that "Skip the counting of the numberMatched attribute" (in layer > publishing) would do the trick but it does not help.

Comment: There seems to be an open enhancement request (https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-10085) that you could encourage work on in the usual ways

Comment: Thanks for that one, Ian. Do you or anyone else have any idea what might cause my first question "SQL statement executed twice"?

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself...

**1. SQL statement executed twice**

The reason was parameter "return bounding box with every feature" in Geoserver WFS settings. I got rid of double execution by unchecking this

[image]

**2. How to remove "select count(*)..."**

Looks like using WFS 1.0.0 is the only solution for this

Answer (score 0):

First time the features are counted [here](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/main/src/wfs/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wfs/GetFeature.java#L541). No way to skip.
Second time the features are counted [here](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/main/src/wfs/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wfs/GetFeature.java#L707). That can be skipped by checking "NumberMatched skip" on the WFS layer settings.

Perhaps putting an index on the table will help with performance of the query.